# search in mysql replacing space with null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query to search phone number.  Simple searching is fine, but I have the following condition.

```
eg : I want to search a number   : 0431248892
```

But the data can be stored in any format in database as users enter it.

Eg :

```
 04 3124 8892
             0431248892
         0431 2488 92
```

Comment: TIP : user `TRIM` before you save data in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE REPLACE(columnname,' ','') = '0431248892'
```

Comment: I'd definitely use trim/replace for INSERT (to prevent blanks in the first place), but I'd use a regex for SELECT (if the data already contains blanks).  IMHO..

Comment: i am also search this query.. thanks.. SELECT *
FROM phone
WHERE REPLACE( pnum, ' ', '' ) = '04315676789'
OR REPLACE( pnum, '-', '' ) = '04315676789'

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a MySql Regex:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html
- http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2337